# Identifying worst case of realized uncertainty

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, robust-optimization

I have a MILP formulation where one of the parameters in the constraints is unknown but comes from a know uncertainty set (Robust Optimization approach). As far as I researched the first step for formulating the robust counterpart is to identify the worst case of the realized uncertainty and either max/or min it.

What are the best ways to identifying the worst case that comes from the uncertainty set?

Comment: What is the form of the uncertainty set? for the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Worst case implies either lower (max)/upper bound (min). I'd try using duality principle as feasible solution to the dual will give me a bound to the primal objective. So you can use the bounds of the random variable as a constraint, solve the dual, then use the value found for the random and the dual bound as constraints on the objective, re-solve.